# How to position an image more accurately

Tags: html, css, image

Is there any way I can position big images more accurately within specific boundaries?

**HTML**

```
<div class="about__office">
  <img src="images/about__ofice.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.about__office img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10em;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

As you can see the image is cropping off the heads of the people. What I want eventually is to somehow add a top padding if possible.

[image]

Comment: I think you want `object-position: top center;` or `object-position: 50% 0;` the img is positioned from the center, you want it to be centered from the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've specified a height in your css (`height: 10em;`).
The image container will always be of this size.

If what you're trying to achieve is to shift the image down without changing its size you should be able to do that by changing your `object-position` values.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position

Comment: I've looked into that documentation but don't understand how to set a top shift to the picture. I played around with the values of my object-position, but nothing.

Comment: @user181475 do you still need help with it?